# Is there any matrix operation can turns all entries of a matrix into squared value?

Tags: linear-algebra

For a matrix $X=[x_{ij}]$, is there exist any matrix operation $F$ such that $F(X) = Y=[x_{ij}^2]$?

p.s. $X$ is a square matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. With the [Hadamard product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_%28matrices%29) $A\circ B=(a_{ij}b_{ij})_{i,j\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}}$, we have $X\circ X=(x_{ij}^2)_{i,j\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}}$.